# Adding spaces to the + operator in Scala gives different results?

Tags: scala

Scala newbie here

Trying

(1).+(2) returns a Int value of 3, so far so good 
but  
1.+(2) returns a Double value of 3.0.

But if you do 
1 . +(2) it returns a Int value of 3. 
 
Note: The only difference between this and the above is the space after the "1"

Does Spaces matter in Scala? Im more curious as to how 1.+(2) returned a Double as it looks like it parsed 1. as a Double and then added "2" to it.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, `1.+(2)` is a double because `1.` is a double and `double + int` returns a double to preserve precision. The addition of a space after the `1` means that the first operand to `+` isn't parsed as a double, so the operation is `int + int` - returning an int.

Comment: thanks, it was just confusing/surprising that spaces could matter in scala.

Comment: `1.` is a single token, so putting a space between the `1` and the `.` will always matter.   `val y = sin x` is different from `val y = sinx` also

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.+(2) is calling the + method on the Double "1.".  This is a carry-over from Java syntax, where "1." is equivalent to 1.0.

Comment: Out of interest, do you know what `1 . + (2)` parses to? Does the `.` get silently ignored?

Comment: In that case, the dot is used to invoke the + method on 1.  Here's another example of using whitespace after . and before the method name:  val nums = 1 :: 2 :: Nil; nums . reverse

Comment: @SubmittedDenied: think of it as `ONE.plus(TWO)`.

Comment: Oh I know, the issue was this it was more like ONE . plus(TWO) in this example